# jquery ui tabs help

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

Why is it so hard to use the jquery tab UI :S..

i have download it without the theme cause i want to make my own because i dont want million of CSS just to make that tab effect :S.

so i need to work with the CSS now so i can hide the content and when i click on a link i should shold the content..

this is what i have now:

```
<script>
var $tabs = $('#tabs-1').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#tabs-1').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
</script>
                <div id="tabs">
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
                           </ul>
                           <div id="tabs-1">
                              <p>Tab 1 content</p>
                           </div>
                           <div id="tabs-2">
                              <p>Tab 2 content</p>
                           </div>
                           <div id="tabs-3">
                              <p>Tab 3 content</p>
                           </div>
                        </div><!-- tabs -->

#tabs ul{
    width: 296px;
    float: left;
}

#tabs li {
    float: left;
    width: 95px;
    text-align: center;
}

#tabs-1 {

}

#tabs-2 {
    display: none;
}

#tabs-3 {
    display: none;
}
```

hope some one can help me out im confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs-1').tabs();
```

must be

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
```

second, you must override or define the css rules if you dont download them

```
.ui-tabs-hide {
 display:none;   
}
```

this you need to have!

And this you dont need at al:

```
$('#tabs-1').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
```

Comment: hm im not sure about the CSS, there do you get ui-tabs-hide from

Comment: Look, jquery is very much based on css. if you click a tab, jquery removes the panel cssclass "ui-tabs-hide". If you dont believe try it yourself, here http://jsfiddle.net/theluk/eJXCN/

Comment: Thanks @luke , but i still dont know where do you know this class exsists ".ui-tabs-hide" :P?

Comment: i just look into the code what it´s doing... and on there page is a documentation about "theming".

Comment: i can only see this: <div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
   <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
   <div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab one content goes here.</p>
   </div>
    ...
</div>

Comment: i cant find anything about the .ui-tabs-hide class